# Integrals of motion for a rotational symmetric 3D Hamiltonian $H=\frac{{\bf p}^2}{2m}+V(r)$

Tags: homework-and-exercises, conservation-laws, coordinate-systems, hamiltonian-formalism, integrals-of-motion

> A particle of mass $m$ moves in three dimensions under the action of the conservative force with potential energy $V(r)$. Using the spherical coordinates $r, \theta, \phi$ find the Hamiltonian of the problem, show that  $p_Φ$, $p_r^2/(2m)+p_Φ^2/(2mr^2\sin^2θ)+V(r)$ and $p_θ^2+p_Φ^2/\sin^2θ $ are constants of motion.

In this problem $p_Φ$ can be easily proved constant as $Φ$ is cyclic co-ordinate, but how can we prove the rest two, I approached by trying to solve differential equation for the motion but, in every equation at least two variables appearing, I can't solve it that way, what should I use to do this problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you know how to use Poisson brackets, you can use them. For $f(q,p,t)$:
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}f}{\mathrm{d}t} = \{f,H\}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}.$$
If you don't know Poisson brackets, you can (equivalently) use the equations of motion. I'll give an example using the Simple Harmonic Oscillator.

For the SHO, $H=\frac{p^{2}}{2m}+\frac{1}{2}kx^{2}$. The equations of motion are:

\begin{align}
    \dot{x} = \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}t} &= \frac{\partial H}{\partial p} = \frac{p}{m}\\
    \dot{p} = \frac{\mathrm{d}p}{\mathrm{d}t} &= -\frac{\partial H}{\partial x} = -kx.
\end{align}

To show that the Hamiltonian is a constant of motion, we calculate its total/ordinary time derivative:

\begin{align}
    \frac{\mathrm{d}H}{\mathrm{d}t} &= \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}\left(\frac{p^{2}}{2m}+\frac{1}{2}kx^{2}\right)\\
    &= \frac{p}{m}\dot{p} + kx\dot{x}\\
\end{align}
Using the equations of motion we get:
\begin{align}
    &= \frac{p}{m}(-kx) + kx\left(\frac{p}{m}\right)\\
    &= 0.
\end{align}
This shows that the Hamiltonian is a constant of motion. The procedure can be adapted to other quantities that depend on $x$ and $p$ as well.

Comment: Appreciated for the help